# How to limit the items in popup?

Tags: livecode

How to limit the items in the popup. "Sar" array contains lot of words, with respect to the selection. if my first popup contains 15 items and did the change. when going to the next popup, if it contains 10 items, the remains 5 items from the first also added to the second popup options. 
How to kill that buffer in popup menu items? Iam using this code

```
    global jar,myjar,sam,mySam,Dic,Sar
on mouseUp pMouseButton
   put the selectedText of field "MytextField" into Ftext

   if pMouseButton = 3 then

      put the number of lines of (the keys of sam) into mySam
      repeat with i = 1 to mySam 
         if sam[i] contains Ftext then
            put sam[i] into Sar
            split Sar by comma
         end if
      end repeat

      put the text of button "M" into tText
      put the number of words of (the keys of Sar) into mylength
      repeat with x = 1 to mylength 
         put Sar[x] into line x of tText
         end repeat
      put mylength into kk---now iam using this code for delete the buffer
      ----repeat with j = kk to 100
         ---put "" into line j of tText
      ---end repeat
      set the text of button "M" to tText
      popup button "M" at the clickLoc 
   else
      --popup button "M" at the clickLoc
      -- do other stuff here
   end if
end mouseUp
```

Is any option for limit the items in popup. Example:- if popup contains 15 items, i want to see only 10 items, remaining 5 could be see only clicking the bottom button in the popup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `globals` which might not be what you want.

Try emptying the global with `put empty into Sar` before adding some new values or use `locals` which will be emptied after your code is done.

Comment: Sorry Tate. Its not working. is there any option to delete items from popup list? but that deleted item does not shows with empty content.

Comment: I used this code "delete line j of tText" and now its work fine